# Spherical average of $\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, integration

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be points on $\mathbb S^1.$

We then define the expectation value $E(X)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i.$

Let $\frac{dS(X_1)}{2\pi}$ be the normalized surface measure of $\mathbb S^1,$ i.e. $X_i$ are uniformly distributed random variables on the circle.

I am curious to know:

How does

$$\int_{(\mathbb S^1)^n } \frac{1}{\vert E(X) \vert}\frac{dS(X_1)}{2\pi}...\frac{dS(X_n)}{2\pi}$$
scale with $n$?

Comment: A quick guess would be the Central limit theorem  $\sim \sqrt{n}$

Comment: @RaphaelB4 would you mind elaborating a bit on this point?

Comment: See the distribution in Carlo.s answer : $e^{-R^2/n}$: the Gaussian with variance $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probability distribution $P(R)$ of $R=n|E(X)|$ was calculated by [Kluyver](https://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00013859.pdf) (1906), it is given by
$$P(R)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^\infty [J_0(x)]^n J_0(rx)x\,dx.$$
For $n\gg 1$ one has a Rayleigh distribution (here is [derivation](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177728540) including higher order corrections):
$$P(R)=\frac{2R}{n}e^{-R^2/n}.$$
The desired integral then becomes
$$I=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{n}{R}P(R)\,dR\rightarrow \sqrt{\pi n}$$
in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.